# Using android to download file from lighttpd server will show Untitled and download failed

Tags: android, linux, lighttpd

I have lighttpd download server in linux.
       I use the android built-in browser to download files.
       Tried zip, pdf, exe file type can not download.
       Will show Untitled and download failed.
       How do I go to solve this problem?

thanks all!

Comment: Did you ever resolve this issue?

Comment: Does it work in a desktop browser? Try Chrome, that's the closest thing to how that mobile browser works (Webkit core). How are you connecting? WiFi or your mobile provider? (censorship?)

Comment: Did you configure lighttpd.conf with [mimetype.assign](https://wiki.lighttpd.net/Mimetype_assignDetails) ?